# error in setting up an bitmap to an ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an app in android where I'm returning some pictures from facebook pages.I return this pictures as `InputStream` and then I decode them using `BitmapFactory` something like this:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content);
```

After that I tried to set up this bitmap to an `ImageView` but I get force close.This is how I do it:

```
 public Bitmap doInBackground(String...arg0)
        {
            URL profilePicUrl=null;
            int nr=0;
            Bitmap profilePicBitmap=null;
    final String imageURL="http://graph.facebook.com/"+arg0[0]+"/picture?type=small";
                 try{

profilePicBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
            System.out.println("Returnam poza numarul:"+profilePicBitmap);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return profilePicBitmap;
                    }

public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        ImageView imageView_1=null;
        Log.d("We are:","Loaded the pictures");
        imageView_1.setImageBitmap(result);

    }
```

I use an `AsyncTask` thread to return the pictures from an URL.But I get error at this line:

```
imageView_1.setImageBitmap(result);
```

When I try to display the result returned from decoding the `InputStream` in here:

```
profilePicBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
                System.out.println("Returnam poza numarul:"+profilePicBitmap);
```

This is what I get:

```
android.graphics.Bitmap@44e38ee0
android.graphics.Bitmap@44e22010
android.graphics.Bitmap@44dfbe68
android.graphics.Bitmap@44de26f8
android.graphics.Bitmap@44daa718
android.graphics.Bitmap@44dc30a0
android.graphics.Bitmap@44daa080
android.graphics.Bitmap@44de1680
android.graphics.Bitmap@44df7140
android.graphics.Bitmap@44dae9d8
android.graphics.Bitmap@44e5b008
android.graphics.Bitmap@44e0ee20
```

This is how my logcat looks like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.SplashScreen.InviteFriends$Task.onPostExecute(InviteFriends.java:214)
at com.SplashScreen.InviteFriends$Task.onPostExecute(InviteFriends.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me cause I don't know what is wrong!

Comment: ImageView imageView_1=null;
        Log.d("We are:","Loaded the pictures");
        imageView_1.setImageBitmap(result);
What does that mean??? You're setting the imageView to null and then trying to call it? No wonder you get a NullPointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onPostExecute` change

```
ImageView imageView_1=null;
```

to

```
ImageView imageView_1= new ImageView(ClassName.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

there are many question of **"How to download image from url"** in StackOverflow.

see this [download image](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%20%5Ddownload%20image%20from%20url) you could get your solution from this question-answer

Comment: Ok...I got it bymyself...just sometimes I'm so dull!

Comment: @adrian hey hola! por el nombre he supuesto que eras español, llevo buscando solucion a esto mismo pero esta solucion no me ayuda porque tengo un ImageView personalizado, me puedes echar una mano, te pongo aqui el [link de mi pregunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886415). a ver si es alguna chorrada que no consigo ver,